# Powershell Set FileVersion

Tags: powershell, versioning

I have a script with associated modules, and I would like to add file versioning. Basically I want to update the file versioning when I sign the code, and the code will get the file version of the PS1 file, then check it against the file version of all the PSM1 files and log an error if they don't match.

That said, I can use

```
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("somefilepath").FileVersion
```

to get the info, but I can't find an y information in how to set the version. Is that because file versions are the bailiwick of compiled EXEs and DLLs and I don't really have a way to add file versioning to script files? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't find an y information in how to set the version. Is that **because file versions are the bailiwick of compiled EXEs and DLLs** and I don't really have a way to add file versioning to script files?

You already almost answered your own question, that is exactly it! :)

`FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` wraps a call to a native api function ([`version.dll!GetFileVersionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoa)).

The current version of the version API supports a wide range of file formats with PE files (`.exe`,`.dll`) being the obvious ones.

Other formats like OLE controls (`.ocx`), screensavers (`.scr`), drivers (`.drv`,`.sys`), installers (`.msi`,`.msu`) and MUI language pack resources (`.mui`) can all have embedded version information that can be parsed using the same library, so it's not *just* executables.

Your `.ps1` file on the other hand is just a text file - *the operating system wouldn't know where in it's content to look for and parse version information*.

For this, you'd have to either tack a comment onto the last line of the file and store the version there, store the version info in the file name, abuse a comment-based help keyword field (like `.REMARKS` for example), or store it in an alternate data stream (assuming all machines in your build/signing tool chain are running NTFS):

```
# write version info to an alternate data stream
Set-Content -Value "1.4.884.3" -Path script.ps1 -Stream myVersion

# read it back during build
$versionString = Get-Content script.ps1 -Stream myVersion
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. I suspect I will address it with a Getter function that returns the module version, and revise the value with my "build" utility that also signs the code. Not perfect, in that I can't verify version number of a file manually without opening the file, but still allows me to validate correct modules at launch, which is the real goal.

Comment: @Mathias : setting stream is cool, where does it store the information, I can access this stream even from a different session.

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV ADS is an NTFS feature (so it's stored along side the actual file contents in the file system), it's the same thing that's used to store zone information when you download files from the internet for example

Comment: ok, just got curious, https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L8295
is the file getting recreated ?

Comment: the resultpath is `$"{path}:{streamName}"` , but I can see the DateModified attribute is changed for the particular file when added a new stream content.

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV poke me on twitter instead, SO comments are not for long unrelated discussions :)